# Android Google Maps - how to check if Polyline is null

Tags: java, android, google-maps-api-3, google-polyline

I am trying to check if my `polyline` variable contains any assigned `polylineoptions`.

When the activity loads, the `onMapReady` method is automatically called and thus I get a compiler error when I try to set the points of a polyline to null (see code below)

Assignment of data to a polyline looks something like this:

```
    mMap = googleMap;
    double[] firstCoords;
    double[] lastCoords;
    double[] receivedDataArray;
    double latitude;
    double longitude;

    ArrayList<LatLng> coordList = new ArrayList<LatLng>();
    coordList.clear();


    polyline.setPoints(null); //ERROR HERE


    for (int i = 0; i < coordinatesArray.size() - 1; i++) {
        receivedDataArray = coordinatesArray.get(i);

        latitude = receivedDataArray[0];
        longitude = receivedDataArray[1];

        coordList.add(new LatLng(latitude,longitude));
    }

    options = new PolylineOptions().addAll(coordList).width(10).color(Color.BLUE).geodesic(true);
    polyline = mMap.addPolyline(options);
```

I attempted to do a check to see if the polyline contains any data but I get compiler errors as well on both of these checks:

```
if(polyline.getOptions() != null){
   polyline.setPoints(null); 
}
```

or

```
if(!polyline.getOptions().isEmpty()) {
   polyline.setPoints(null); 
}
```

error when checking for null:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.util.List com.google.android.gms.maps.model.Polyline.getPoints()' on a null object reference
```

How can I check if polyline has any points assigned to it when the Activity first loads?

Comment: Why would you want to set it to `null`?

Comment: @Barns because if I don't, the polylines actually don't get erased form the map when you try to load a new set of coordinates for polylines EVEN IF THE ARRAY IS CLEARED

Comment: Removing all entries from your "coordList" and calling `polyline.remove()` on your `PolyLine`object before adding new `LatLng` values to your list doesn't work?

Comment: @Barns unfortunately not, I tried that as well. The problem is with `onMapReady` method from google. It is invoked when the Activity loads, at which point no polyline data actually exists! Hence, trying to remove or set something to null when there is no data present throws this `nullpointerexception` and I am struggling of a way to get around it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Removing all entries from your "coordList" and calling `polyline.remove()` on your PolyLine object or `mMap.clear()` to remove all markings before adding new LatLng values to your list of coordinates.

Make these class variables:

```
PolyLine mPolyline;
ArrayList<LatLng> mCoordList = new ArrayList<LatLng>();
GoogleMap mMap;
```

Now all you have to do is add the polylines when you need to:

```
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap){

    mMap = googleMap;

    addPolylineToMap();
}

private void addPolylineToMap(){
    double[] receivedDataArray;
    double latitude;
    double longitude;
    // Clear the list first
    mCoordList.clear();

    for (int i = 0; i < coordinatesArray.size() - 1; i++) {
        receivedDataArray = coordinatesArray.get(i);

        latitude = receivedDataArray[0];
        longitude = receivedDataArray[1];

        mCoordList.add(new LatLng(latitude,longitude));
        Log.e(TAG, "List size = " + mCoordList.size());
    }

    //You can also call ...
    //mMap.clear();
    //...in order to remove all markings on the map

    if(mPolyline != null){
        mPolyline.remove();
    }

    options = new PolylineOptions().addAll(coordList).width(10).color(Color.BLUE).geodesic(true);
    mPolyline = mMap.addPolyline(options);
}
```

Note: I think you could probably optimize the object `coordinatesArray` to be more efficient.